# Avira SDK Configure to IOS APP (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, sdk

Hi guys i need help in Objective C, i'am trying to configure Avira SDK in my IOS app. There are some error while am build the app. I have attached the screenshot below.

```
undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFPhotoEditorController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Aviary.o
  "_kAFDraw", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFEffects", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFMeme", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFWhiten", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFFrames", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFText", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFRedeye", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFBlemish", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFSharpness", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFCrop", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFEnhance", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFOrientation", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
  "_kAFStickers", referenced from:
      -[Aviary show:] in Aviary.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue actually i have miss the

```
CoreData.Framework.
```

Now its working.